# Mix arrays to one sorting like even-odd

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

Is it possible to inject data after every data in array, or mix arrays together?

eg:

column *A* has three cells with `data1`, `data2`, `data3`
column *B* has three cells with `data1a`, `data2a`, `data3a`

`TRANSPOSE(A:A)` has `data1, data2, data3` and I want `data1, data1a, data2, data2a, data3, data3b`

Answer (score 1):

My solution (there's probably a simpler way):

In C1

```
=concatenate(arrayformula(JOIN(",",A1:B1)),",")
```

Drag it down for the remainder of the rows (3 in the example you gave), to get them all in a string, give a cell the equation:

```
=join("",C1:C3)
```

Alternatively, to make a vertical list in cells (without commas), don't use that use:

```
=transpose(split(join("",C1:C3),","))
```

If you get stuck just try and use variations on these in different columns, then stick them in order into one equation (called "nesting")

Hope that helps :-)